# how can i execute my script in any location from command line?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, path

I have script in /opt location and if i want to run that script i have to go to /opt location and need to run that script. But i want to run that script any location from command line. what i have to do?

For ex : script.sh is in /opt location. To execute this script i have to provide with location path also. ./opt/script.sh.

I want to execute this script from location without providing location.

like from root if i give ./script.sh, it has to execute. Do need to add this location path in any init.d script?

Running the script to update command line arguments into a file.
script --name "aaaa", name value updating in a file.
If i give this command from any location through command line, file needs to update.

Comment: If you move it to `/usr/bin` or another directory in `$PATH` (or add `/opt` to your PATH), you won't have to specify location. It's the responsibility of the script to find whichever files it modifies.

Comment: There's a strong convention around putting executables in a directory ending with `/bin`. You may want to put the script in `/opt/bin` and then add that to your PATH.

Answer (score 1):

You want to copy/move your script to one of the folders specified by the `PATH` variable. This is where Bash looks for programs. View this list like this:

```
echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n'
```

On Ubuntu, `~/bin` is a good place to put programs because you always have read and write access here. Using `sudo` you could place it in any of those folders, but this should work for you:

```
cp script.sh ~/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one,
save this line in you ~/.bash_profile file,

```
PATH=$PATH:/opt/
```

and that's it. Run your script from anywhere like a bash command.

Hope that helps.